# Running slim framework on existing apache web server

Tags: php, apache, slim

I am new to slim framework. Currently on my existing webserver which is on centos 7 I have other php based application running. So currently my directory structure is like this.

```
var/www/html
    phpapp1
    phpapp2
    apislim
```

The folder for the apislim I created was for slim framework.
Below are the exact steps I did was
1. composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton
2. I rename the slim-skeleton folder to apislim
3. I make sure the owner is apache chown -R apache:apache apislim
4. In the httpd.conf I ensure this AllowOverride is enabled to be All

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Also below I enabled All

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">   
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

5. In the apislim/public folder I have this .htaccess file as below.

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
     RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
6. The I have also the index.php file in the public folder which also links up to the src for the routes and the main folder apislim I created another .htaccess file and added this.

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

The issue now I want my existing application to work along with this rest api which is based on slim framework. So when I go to this link

```
http://*.*.*.*/apislim/
http://*.*.*.*/apislim/public/
http://*.*.*.*/apislim/public/index.php
```

Neither of it works all are giving me 403 forbidden. Then I check the error log it show error regarding FollowSymLinks
So I added 
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
Into

So next error I get now is 500 interval server error.

Comment: Check your Apache error log - it should give you some hint as to why the 500 error is occurring. Also check and make sure you have a recent enough version of PHP - the most recent version of Slim requires PHP 5.5 or later, and CentOS 7 ships with PHP 5.4.

Comment: @VirtuallyNick I have all the latest version php 7 centos 7. Actually is it possible to run slim framework with existing application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "run slim framework with existing application?"  It can certainly co-exist with other items on the same server, but the Apache configuration would need to be done correctly such that the RewriteRule entries from one do not interfere with the other, and vice-versa.

Comment: Can you try this two .htaccess files? [file1](https://github.com/odan/prisma/blob/master/.htaccess), [file2](https://github.com/odan/prisma/blob/master/public/.htaccess)

Comment: @VirtuallyNick yes I wanted to confirm can it can co-exist. Thank you

Comment: @DanielO where you want me to file1 and file2 ?

Comment: The first file into `var/www/html/apislim`, the second file into: `var/www/html/apislim/public`.

Comment: Ok I am getting message now Page Not Found
The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you can visit our home page at the link below.. This is from the slim framework error I guess

Comment: The default slim-skeleton route has this $app->get('/[{name}]', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Sample log message
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");

    // Render index view
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml', $args);
});

Comment: Ok now add this small [container entry](https://github.com/odan/prisma/blob/master/config/container.php#L32) to fix the 'environment' into the file dependencies.php:

Comment: Where to add this line of codes ?

Comment: In dependencies.php

Comment: Ok I added into the /src/dependencies.php its working now.But I added this extra route in the route.php 
$app->get('/test1', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    echo "TEST";
}) Its not working but giving me error message 500

Comment: `echo` is not allowed in Slim, because it's a PSR-7 based framework. Use this code instead: `$response->getBody()->write("Hello World"); return $response;`. [Example](https://github.com/odan/prisma/blob/master/src/Controller/UserController.php#L124)

Comment: Actually why this extra settings making it working but when I add the extra route $app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    echo "TEST";
}); It failed to run with this error now Static route "/test1" is shadowed by previously defined variable route "/([^/]+)" for method "GET"

Comment: i get same error with this new syntax $app->get('/test1', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    return $response->getBody()->write("Hello World");

});

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I updated the last comment.

Comment: @DanielO no problem maybe too many things we got mixed up. I think almost solving the issue ready.

Comment: Ok I create a full answer and you accept it ok?

Comment: Ok sure please I am thankful to you but also help me resolve on the test1 which I just added

Comment: Just set the value `displayErrorDetails` to `true` in [settings.php](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/master/src/settings.php#L4) to see the exact error message.

Comment: Yes its actually in true mode ready. I got this error now Static route "/test1" is shadowed by previously defined variable route "/([^/]+)" for method "GET" but I dont have other get except for the first one that is the detault one $app->get('/[{name}]', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

Comment: There is probably a "conflict" between your 'root' route and this optional: `/[{name}]` route, because both could match the path '/'. Change the second route to `/{name}`.

Comment: Also the root route is not correct. Change it to '/'.

Comment: Ok that looks like solved the issue. So the default /[{name}] is wrong is it ?

Comment: The square brackets means: This is a optional parameter. In combination with the root route `/` this is problematic. I think `/` for the first route and `/{name}` for the second route should be fine. [More details](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#route-placeholders)

Comment: @Daniel so what is your opinion did I do enough settings? How to harden this slim-skeleton I saw many codes which I dont know will I be using all ? How to secure further ?

Comment: You can find more infos about this topic [here](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2#deployment).

Comment: @DanielO I read this For security reasons you MUST set the Apache DocumentRoot of the webhosting to the public folder. Otherwise, it may happen that someone else accesses the internal files from outside. So in my case my application with coexist with other web application. What is your advice should I separate the web application and the rest api into different server ?

Comment: In your case, you could create separate domains/subdomains for each application/api/site. Then there will be no dangerous overlaps with the sessions/cookies. On which server the api/page is running doesn't matter much.

Comment: @DanielO ok I think I will run based on subdomain basis. Normally wont running both web and this api will incur for stress on a single server? What is your advice to go with slim or build own api ? Is there any security loop holes I must be aware ?

Comment: Slim is perfect for RESTful API and also very good for websites and web appications. Security depends on what you want to implement (API/Website/Application). I cannot give a specific answer to this general question.

Comment: @DanielO I want to keep it more to api. So what and how should I harden ? Sorry I am very new to rest api that is why I am kind of lost but thank you cause manage to resolve this issue.

Comment: Read this: [REST, RESTful, REST-like API Resources](https://gist.github.com/odan/de7f5452fb165c2d27f20d1d16bfe54d)

and this: [REST, RESTful API Quick Reference](https://gist.github.com/odan/1d2ef018adb3ea5a0d3abb35406d2c65)

Comment: @DanielO thank you surely I read up dont forget to you update your answer. I will have few more question on this slim cause I was just testing this link https://trinitytuts.com/secure-your-php-web-services-using-jwt/ and saw this error PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Tuupola\Middleware\Cors' not found in  but I will open a new question on this

Comment: @DanielO do not forget to add your solution so I can marked as accepted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following steps are necessary for your Slim 3 application to work within subdirectories.

Directory structure:

- `public/`      Web server files (the [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html#documentroot))

  - `.htaccess`   Apache redirect rules for the front controller
  - `index.php`   The front controller
- `.htaccess`    Internal redirect to the public/ directory

The content of the file: `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The content of the file: `public/.htaccess`:

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Add this container entry to the file: `dependencies.php`:

```
// Activating routes in a subfolder
$container['environment'] = function () {
    $scriptName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = dirname(dirname($scriptName)) . '/' . basename($scriptName);
    return new Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER);
};
```

**Edit**: In Slim 4 you should use the `$app->setBasePath($basePath);` method. [More details](https://github.com/selective-php/basepath)

Comment: @Daniel0 I dont is this section DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/htdocs/public because currently this how my structure is var/www/html
    phpapp1
    phpapp2
    apislim . So how do I do in reference to my scenario ? Currently in my conf I saw this DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" Isnt this the default location for my other application too?

Comment: I have formulated the answer in a more general way. Of course, the root directories are different for each host. To avoid any misunderstandings I removed the last section.

Comment: @Daniel0 what will be the exact step for nginx. I am trying to move to nginx but its not working according I tried with try files is not working. Any guidance how to repeat and making it work on nginx ?

Comment: `.htaccess` files are not supported by nginx. If you use nginx just read this Slim [user guid](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html#nginx-configuration) section.

Comment: @Daniel0 I tried the link you gave it keep pointing to the index.php in the /var/www/html only. I quite lost I tried many different option and method all seems not giving any solution. Is there any special settings for nginx

Comment: I have created a new question this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685105/nginx-slim-framework-keep-pointing-to-the-main-index-in-root-folder. Just wondering does you dependencies.php apply for nginx cause I applied it ready into the nginx version too.

Answer (score 0):

For the past couple years, @odan solution was working for me in apache.
Now I started using php8.0 builtin server for development, but it didn't work there.

Don't ask me how, or why, or how many hours I've lost to this problem, but the solution was a simple `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = null;` somewhere before calling  Slim's run method.