# Slim Framework index.php in public folder .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim, slim-3

I'm using Slim Framework v3, in particular I'm using this project: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton

My problem is to run my project on an apache server, if I try to reach with this url http://localhost/slim-app/some_route I receive this error:

[image: error1]

But if I try to navigate to http://localhost/slim-app/public/some_route it works.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/slim-app
 .htaccess
 /logs
 /public
  /css
  /js
  index.php
  .htaccess
 /src
  /helpers
  routes.php
  settings.php
 /templates
  file.twig
 /vendor
```

This is the .htaccess file in the root project folder "slim-app":

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /slim-app/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This is the .htaccess file in the public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
  # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
  # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
  # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
  # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
  # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
  # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
  # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  # If the above doesn't work you might need to set the `RewriteBase` directive manually, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  # RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My experience trying to make Slim work in a subdirectory is that it isn't a supposed scenario and doesn't normally work. I suggest you move your code elsewhere and create an [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to `public`. That's also safer since the rest of the source code is totally outside the web server directory tree. Still, you can maybe find some other issues anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932959/running-slim-framework-on-existing-apache-web-server/48945514#48945514

Comment: thanks for reporting me this, but it fixes only a part of the issue, this solves the routing issue.
If in my code I have an a HTML tag like this: <a href="/some-route">link</a>  it doesn't route to: http://localhost/slim-app/some_route, instead routes to: http://localhost/some_route.
@odan

Comment: Also, if I manually route to: http://localhost/slim-app/some_route, another issue occours:  
While resources are loaded inside the public slim-app folder:
i.e.: http://localhost/slim-app/css/style.css;
when i load the index sub-route it goes on looking for resources in the routed page.
http://localhost/slim-app/some_route/css/style.css
@odan

Comment: Are you using Slim to *generate* the links you mention?

Comment: Yes, the css route is a folder located in the public folder, but some_route is a slim route @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: I mean the value in `href` at `<a href="/some-route">link</a>`. Do you generate such HTML using Slim or it's hard-coded in your HTML template?

Comment: it's hard-coded @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: it seems that with this {{ base_url() }} before the link route the issue is resolved

Comment: Tipp: The slim/twig-view component exposes a custom [path_for](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/features/templates.html#the-path_for-method) function to generate links.

Comment: I do slim apps in sub directories. In order to do that I have virtual hosts in my apache .conf that have a document root point to the subfolder/public folder.